# Does dnsmasq have a functionality to create the DNS entries automatically for the addresses it is listening on?

Tags: dnsmasq

I'm running `dnsmasq` as a caching name server on a LAN facing bridge named `br4`. `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` contains "bind-interfaces" and "interface=br4". Currently I'm running a script which reads all the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on `br4` interface and builds a file for `dnsmasq` "addn-hosts" option. Does `dnsmasq` have a functionality to create the DNS entries automatically for the addresses it is listening on using the hostname of the server?

For example if `dnsmasq` is listening on UDP and TCP port 53 on addresses `192.168.0.1` and `fe80::a7:29ff:fea6:aa41` in server named `s1`, then perhaps it can create an `A` record for `s1` resolving to `192.168.0.1`, `AAAA` record for `s1` resolving to `fe80::a7:29ff:fea6:aa41` and also the corresponding PTR records all automatically.